# I want my Winform to constantly check for a change in database entry while it is runnning

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012

I have two applications running. One is recognizing user's gestures/face/voice as input and updating database on successfull authentication. The other is Winform which will trigger button_click action on database entry. My question is for WinForms. How can I constantly check the database for new entries while my form is running?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a52dhwx7(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: @ta.speot.is Sorry I just added an answer with the same link you posted. I deleted it after I found out you posted it as comment. I also saved the link a long time ago. Kandarp Joshi listen to this guy, he's directing you to exactly the thing you want :)

Comment: @chris_techno25 Yes man. I'm listening to both of you. And now following a bit, too.

Comment: @ta.speot.is  ... Can I undelete my answer because I added a few information based on my experience :) And I have the same link you posted, just coincidence :) Is that alright?

Comment: Don't worry about me, post what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a separate thread/Task that will periodically check the database.

Example with a Thread instance (on ConsoleApplication but you can easily move it to WinForms):

```
class Program
{
    public static void CheckSomethingInDb()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            // do periodical check 
            Console.WriteLine("Periodical check"); 
            Thread.Sleep(500); 
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dbCheckerThread = new Thread(CheckSomethingInDb);
        dbCheckerThread.IsBackground = true;
        dbCheckerThread.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("... the application is running further..."); 
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

With Task it is very similar:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task dbCheckerThread = new Task(CheckSomethingInDb);
        dbCheckerThread.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("... the application is running further..."); 
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Although in general a recommended practice is to separate your user application (in your case WinForms app) from the agents that do some periodical checks/integrations/synchronizations. So it would be best to have a separate Windows Service or some other simple app running separately from your main app.